# Relative path fails in a submodule

Tags: python, git

I have a python project A, this project is distributed to clients as-is. Inside project A I use hard coded paths to files in this project (w.r.t its working directory). Let's say I have a db file in project A located under `resources/employees.db`

I also have project B, which is also distributed to clients. in project B, project A is listed as a git submodule, located in folder `projectA`, when I try to start project B it fails, as it can't initialize project A due to unfound file:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'resources/employees.db'
```

It makes sense, w.r.t to the working directory of project B, the file should be loaded from `projectA/resources/employees.db`. But of course changing this relative path in project A is not acceptable. How to solve this conflict?

Comment: The code to open the file is in project A? And you can't change project A?

Comment: These are projects, like, for example, notebooks? Not Python packages?

Comment: The code to open is in project A, that's correct, and you can change it. A notebook is not a project, think of a project as a git repo

Comment: The problem is that you are not saying what kind of projects these repositories are, and how they are run. If they are packages, for example, you install them, and the problem should go away. But I guess they are more like a set of scripts or notebooks.

Comment: @9769953 those are 2 applications, each house modules, notebooks, scripts, etc

Comment: @9769953 edited my first answer, The code to open the DB file is in project A, that's correct, and you can change project A.

Comment: You could temporarily change the current working directory to what A expects, let A read the file, then change it back again. But that is a horribly solution, and if A is a standalone "app" of sorts, I doubt it should actually be run as part of B.

Comment: If you *can* change proejct A, then Thomas's solution works. Although I would go so far as to use an absolute path (to get rid of potential symbolic links), but that's a minor addition.

Comment: For an example of using `__file__`, see the Django (a widely used web framework) `settings.py` file ([this is the template file in its repository](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py-tpl). It uses `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`, which uses `pathlib.Path` instead of string paths and `os.path`, but boils down to the same. `resolve()` makes the path absolute, resolving any symbolic links. Further down the `settings.py` file, `BASE_DIR` is used with other paths. This way, the `settings.py` file can be used anywhere.

Comment: @9769953 thank you for the example and taking the time to answer this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a path relative to the current Python file, whose absolute path is helpfully provided for you in the `__file__` global. For example:

```
import os.path

EMPLOYEES_DB_PATH = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    '..', 'resources', 'employees.db')
```

Adjust the number of `'..'` entries according to the location of this Python file.

Comment: You can, but it doesn't make sense from the point of view of project A right? why not just use relative path there? (project A doesn't care that someone use it as a submodule, it's also standalone)

Comment: @Anton.P Because now A can use the path as normal, *and* it can be used indirectly by B. Which is what you want. Why then ask "why not use a relative path"? You get a solution which is more generic, which you then want to throw away?

Comment: @Anton.P Relative paths need something to be relative _to_. This answer how you can provide the something.

Comment: Thx. eventually used this approach